# Is there any prime in the form of $10^n+1$ for $n>2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there any prime in the form of $10^n+1$ for $n>2$ ? It can be seen that $n$ is the form of $2^k$ so that this number is prime.

Comment: This question has been asked here before in various forms.

Comment: Can you send me the link ?

Comment: Can't find it at the moment. To the best of my knowledge, if such prime exists, then $n$ has to be a power of $2$.

Comment: If $n=2^ab$ with $b$ odd, $b\ge 3$, then $$10^n+1=\left(10^{2^a}+1\right) \left(10^{n-2^a}-10^{n-2^a -1}+\cdots-10^1+1\right)$$

Therefore, if $10^n+1$ is prime, then $n=2^a$ is a power of $2$. WolframAlpha says it's not prime for $a\le 9$.

Comment: See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95119/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-62n1-or-only-finitely-many/95124#95124 ($6$ rather than $10$, but the principles are the same).

Comment: @RobertIsrael You mean "$36$ rather than $10$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link

http://www.prothsearch.net/GFN10.html

shows that the smallest unknown cases are $a=24$ and $a=25$. So, if there is a prime of the form $10^n+1$ with $n>2$, then it must have more than $16$ million digits, so the smallest possible magnitude of the prime would be comparable to that of the current largest known prime (recently detected, about $22$ million digits).

It is unknown whether there are finite or infifite many numbers of the form $10^n+1$ , or whether $2$, $11$ and $101$ are even the only ones.

Comment: Thanks Peter, you realy helped. You did not just say" there are some sources".